# append data in user global variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any way that i can append my data into user global variable so i can access it on other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

- You can save it on the user object (`$user->data`), if it's some static data that doesn't change.
- Use [`hook_user`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6) op load which could look like this:

  ```
  function module_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'load':
        $account->module = db_fetch_object(db_query(
          'SELECT * FROM {module} WHERE uid = %d', $account->uid
        ));
        break;
    }
  }
  ```

Hook user, is good if you have complex data that changes a lot. You can store the data in your own table, and append it you the user when it's being loaded. The downside is, that you will need to run [`user_load`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_load/6) you get the data on the user object.

Comment: In you 1st method, how to save it on global user object?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need/want to handle the storage of your data in the database because you just want it the be globally accessible during the user's session, you can store it in the [$_SESSION array](http://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use variable_set() and variable_get()if the data is common to all users else SESSIONS need to be used